# How to invoke method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, nested, private, invoke

`Collections` class has nested class `private static class EmptyList<E>` which has `get(int index)` method and does not have default constructor. How can I invoke `get(int index)` method?

Comment: Are you trying to create an `EmptyList`? If so, use `Collections.emptyList()`. Why are you trying to invoke `get` on an `EmptyList`, it will always throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on why you want to involve a method that throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for every call? But ignoring this you can just call the method on the instance that is returned by `Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: Your question looks like [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need it to throw IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: My actual problem is discribed in question.

Comment: It is a study task.

Comment: `Collections.emptyList().get(0);` will throw the desired exception. Or you could create a new instance of `EmptyList` by calling `Class.forName("java.util.Collections.EmptyList").newInstance()`. Note that this code is not tested by me and might throw some checked exceptions you have to catch. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

Comment: First option does not suit me. Second option does not work, because EmptiList class does not have declared default constructor. Or because EmptyClass is private, I will now check this out/

Comment: Nope, does't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of `java.util.Collections$EmptyList` and call its `get(int)` by using the code below. The code is fully tested and throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as requested.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.util.Collections$EmptyList");
        Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        List<?> emptyList = (List<?>) constructor.newInstance();

        emptyList.get(0);
    }
}
```

Just because I am curious, could you probably provided more information on why you would want to do something like this?

Comment: I am so stupid. I was doing like this `List emptyList = (List) constructor.newInstance();` I want to that because i study java and i have a task: find class with the given discription. It implements List interface. It is a private static nested class inside popular utility class. Indexed access is forbiden and it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. Using reflection find suited class.

Comment: I am stupid again because it works `List emptyList = (List) constructor.newInstance();` this way to. It means I don't remember what was the difference.